# Go TCP server always throwing EOF after connecting

Tags: go, networking, tcp, server

I have an Go routine running a concurrent TCP 4 server, but everytime I connect to it from via Dial, the TCP server throws an error saying only "EOF". Interestingly it is processing the first line of data, but then the connection handle throws the error.

tcp server instance:

```
 if err != nil {
   fmt.Println("an error occured: ")
   fmt.Println(err)
   return
 }


 defer l.Close()

 for {
   conn, err_handle := l.Accept()
   if err_handle != nil {
     fmt.Println("node err: ",err_handle)
     return
   }
   go handle_Connection(conn, topics)
 }
```

handle_Connection:

```
func handle_Connection(conn net.Conn, topics map[string][]string) {
  defer conn.Close()
  fmt.Println("client connected")

  for {
    data, err_handle := bufio.NewReader(conn).ReadString('\n')
    if err_handle != nil {
      fmt.Println("Err: ", err_handle)
      return
    }
```

client:

```
  conn, err := net.Dial("tcp4", ":"+strconv.Itoa(port))

  if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("an error occured: ")
    fmt.Println(err)
  }
```

Comment: Show the complete client code.  Create the bufio.Reader outside the server read loop to avoid discarding data read from the client.

Comment: Please show all of the client code.  The likely problem is that the client closes the connector or exits, but none of that is visible in the linked file.

Answer (score 0):

The very simple fix to the problem is that the server bufio data reader is declared in the loop which is processing the data.

```
func handle_Connection(conn net.Conn, topics map[string][]string) {
  defer conn.Close()
  fmt.Println("client connected")

  for {
    data, err_handle := bufio.NewReader(conn).ReadString('\n')
    if err_handle != nil {
      fmt.Println("Err: ", err_handle)
      return
    }
```

should be:

```
func handle_Connection(conn net.Conn, topics map[string][]string) {
  defer conn.Close()
  fmt.Println("client connected")

  data, err_handle := bufio.NewReader(conn).ReadString('\n')
  for {
    if err_handle != nil {
      fmt.Println("Err: ", err_handle)
      return
    }
```